# Schema.SObjectField getDescribe method get System.SObjectException when calling form different API version

Tags: apex

I have a Schema util class like the following one:

```java
public with sharing class ObjectDescribe {
    public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> getFieldsMap(sObject obj) {
        DescribeSObjectResult describeObject = obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

        return describeObject.fields.getMap();;
    }
}
```

then to call the `getFieldsMap()` method in a class:

```java
public with sharing class TestDescribe {
    public static void execute() {
        Opportunity obj = new Opportunity();
        objectFields = ObjectDescribe.getFieldsMap(obj);

        for (String nm : objectFields.keyset()) {
            DescribeFieldResult fr = objectFields.get(nm).getDescribe();
        }
    }
}
```

The result dependents on the class version:

- Works well:  **ObjectDescribe class** is v48.0, **TestDescribe class** is v48.0
- Got `System.SObjectException`: **ObjectDescribe class**  is v48.0, **TestDescribe class** is v35.0

Why does call the `Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe()` from a low version class that causes the `System.SObjectException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContactId` field may be added in some higher version of `35.0`.

To verify this, make a describe call to workbench's rest explorer on below URLs, below are the results.

1. /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe/

   - `ContactId` exists in fields in `48.0`
2. /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe/

   - `ContactId` does not exist in fields `35.0`

---

Now after running the example, the error it gives on my DEV org is:

> System.SObjectException: Field Opportunity.ContactId is inaccessible in this context

---

The describe call is made in `ObjectDescribe` returns the `ContactId` field as its on `48.0`.

But when you try to make a field describe on fields returned on class with `35.0`, it fails because the `TestDescribe` class runs in lower version of class where `ContactId` field doesn't exists, hence the error.

Note: Usually its a good practice to upgrade the version all your code every few years if not on every release. Version mismatches may lead to hidden errors, this one was relatively easy to verify.

Comment: Thanks for your information.